# Can't find elements of element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

In my tests, I need to first find a specific product, and then do some operations on some subelements of that product. There are many products.

This is my first protractor scripts so bear with me.

```
var prod = element.all(by.css('singleproduct')).get(1);
```

`singleproduct` is a directive.
This is the part of the scripts which breaks:

```
prod.element(by.css(".product-ordering ul li")).each(function(elem) {

})
```

However, I always get `element(...).each is not a function`

HTML:

```
<singleproduct ng-repeat="item in vm.products" item="::item" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 product_tile ng-scope ng-isolate-scope">
   <article ng-class="{'product--active': isSelected}" class="product">
      <section ng-click="toggleDetails()" class="product-content">
         <!-- some prod info --> 
      </section>
      <section>             
         <div class="product-ordering">
            <ul class="product-quantities">
               <!-- ngRepeat: option in ::priceList --> 
               <li ng-repeat="option in ::priceList" class="ng-scope">
                  <!-- this is the LI I want to catch...
               </li>
               <!-- end ngRepeat: option in ::priceList --> 
               <li ng-repeat="option in ::priceList" class="ng-scope">
                  <!-- this is the LI I want to catch...

               </li>
               <!-- end ngRepeat: option in ::priceList --> 
               <li ng-repeat="option in ::priceList" class="ng-scope">
                  <!-- this is the LI I want to catch...
               </li>
               <!-- end ngRepeat: option in ::priceList --> 
            </ul>
         </div>
      </section>
   </article>
</singleproduct>
```

Comment: Nice problem you've got, it inspired to add a new eslint rule for that, follow the github issue if interested: https://github.com/alecxe/eslint-plugin-protractor/issues/57. Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe I didn't know your plugin existed, looks pretty useful!

Comment: I'm an idiot, I've realized that I had this rule implemented: see https://github.com/alecxe/eslint-plugin-protractor/blob/master/docs/rules/no-array-finder-methods.md. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`each()` function will work only with array. but `prod.element(by.css(".product-ordering ul li"))` will return you a `ElementFinder` and not `ElementArrayFinder`. you need to use `product.all()` instead of `product.element()`. Look at below example.

```
prod.all(by.css(".product-ordering ul li")).each(function(elem) {

})
```

Comment: I was just going to answer my own question as I just found out too. Thank you!